# String Parameter in Query

Tags: java, mysql, groovy

I am a Programmer learner.

I want to get MySQL query in following format

```
 select status from training where status in ("Open", "Delivered")
```

from my code

```
if(params.openCheckBox){
    query +=" ( t.status  IN ("+params.openCheckBox+", "+params.DeliveredCheckBox+")" 
    query +=" )"
}
```

but it gives

```
   select status from training where status in (Open, Delivered)
```

Here "" (double quote is missing)

Comment: Why would you need the double quote?

Comment: @MichaelArdan because he is passing `String` values. and `String` values should be wrap with quotes.

Comment: Then use single quote instead

Comment: Why do you add the `grails` tag? If you are using grails - have a look at GORM instead of using native MySQL ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape double quotes with `\`, MySQL Accepts double quotes to wrap strings.

```
query +=" ( t.status  IN (\""+params.openCheckBox+"\", \""+params.DeliveredCheckBox+"\")" 
query +=" )"
```

or
just use single quote

```
query +=" ( t.status  IN ('"+params.openCheckBox+"', '"+params.DeliveredCheckBox+"')" 
query +=" )"
```

the query above is vulnerable with `sql injection`. make use of `PreparedStatement` like the one below

Code Snippet:

```
dbConnection = getDBConnection();
String query = "SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE t.status IN (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, params.openCheckBox);
preparedStatement.setString(2, params.DeliveredCheckBox);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

SOURCES

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)
- [JDBC PreparedStatement Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use single quote instead.

```
query +=" ( t.status  IN ('"+params.openCheckBox+"', '"+params.DeliveredCheckBox+"')"
```